# Is "X is a risk of substance abuse" an ambiguous statement?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, phrase-usage

I recently happened upon a health assessment quiz with the following question:

1. Which is not a risk of substance abuse?

   - Bullying
   - Death from Heart Failure
   - Lack of Coping Skills
   - Addiction

The correct answer is "Death from Heart Failure." It was explained to me that this question is asking, "Which of the following will not lead to substance abuse?"

Does this seem like a good question in terms of wording?

Comment: You're right, it's a poorly worded question. How it's worded now makes it sound like "which of the following would not happen to you if you abuse a substance?" (which makes all four answers technically incorrect, I suppose). The way it was explained to you is much more clear. I would have not understood the question had you not added the explanation.

Comment: "Death from Heart Failure" is a huge risk *of* substance abuse, so it's definitely not what you want.  It's  a poor question for another reason though--if  I know nothing about the material, I would be able to guess that dead people have zero risk from any behavior, because they're already dead.

Comment: If this is a quiz given to anyone in the field of health (either student or otherwise), it would be entirely clear, I believe. In this context "Risk of substance abuse" always means "something that puts you at risk of abusing substances", not "a possible result of abusing substances."  Because it's a term that's commonly used in the field, it wouldn't make sense for the term to have two alternative meanings, or psychologists/physicians/health workers would constantly have to clarify a person's words. An online search will show this. I thought this was also understood to an extent in general.

Comment: @Zebrafish: "Risk of substance abuse" can be used in ways like "X increases the risk of substance abuse" or "X has a risk of substance abuse", but I don't think it can be used in the structure "X **is a risk of substance abuse**" to say "X contributes to substance abuse". Can you give an example from the web? I wrote an answer where I quote two examples that seem to show the usage that the original poster expected

Comment: @sumelic It's a fact that in the health professions it means exactly what I said. I looked through the first four pages of a google search and all except one (your second example) mean that.  Your first example is not the same, "substance abuse puts one at risk for Y" compared to "Y is a risk factor of substance abuse." It's true that your second one is a valid counterexample to my claim, I'm not sure what to say to that. All I know is that this exact phrase is used among people in this field, including in the names of papers, and it really wouldn't do for it to be understood in two ways.

Comment: @sumelic In popular culture I thought it was understood much the same way, but that's probably my mistaken perception.

Comment: @sumelic Excuse me, I see what you're saying. You're saying you won't find an instance specifically "is a risk of substance abuse." Yes, you're right, from the results I've seen it almost always said as raises or increases the risk of substance abuse, as in "ADHD Increases Risk of Substance Abuse". I may be wrong, but I take this to mean that the condition of ADHD is a risk of substance abuse." But I don't believe that changes the fact that "risk of substance abuse" overwhelmingly in the health profession, (nearly always), means factors which can contribute to abusing substances, not results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is badly written, to the extent that I also could not understand what it was asking when I first read it. I disagree with Zebrafish's comment saying

> If this is a quiz given to anyone in the field of health (either student or otherwise), it would be entirely clear, I believe. In this context "Risk of substance abuse" always means "something that puts you at risk of abusing substances", not "a possible result of abusing substances."

Here are two examples of "is a risk of substance abuse" being used to mean "is a potential negative result of substance abuse":

- > Alcohol and drugs affect your judgment and can lead to dangerous behavior that puts you at risk for:
  >
  > - [...]
  > - **Unwanted pregnancy.** For the same reasons that alcohol and other drugs put people at greater risk for STDs, it also **makes pregnancy a risk of substance abuse**.

  –"[Drug and Alcohol Abuse Awareness](https://www.porterchester.com/upload/PCI-Drug-and-Alcohol-Abuse-Awareness.pdf)", *Porter and Chester Institute* (Porter and Chester Institute is a technical school)
- > [Suicide is a Hidden Risk of Substance Abuse](http://www.nationalscreeningcenters.com/lisitng/suicide-is-a-hidden-risk-of-substance-abuse)

  –National Screening Centers blog, 2018

I would expect "risk of substance abuse" to be used in the following ways when describing some thing "X" that contributes to substance abuse:

- X carries a risk of substance abuse
- X increases the risk of substance abuse
- X is linked to increased risk of substance abuse